# On hover set wider absolute positioned element but to the opposite side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have a list of Font Awesome icons on the outer bottom side of a Bootstrap column. Currently I have positioned them absolutely and when I set bigger width or bigger padding on hover that icon will grow bigger to the left, while I want it to go on the right.

How do I set it to go on the right, and also how to stop second element from reacting? That feature isn't planned :)
If someone has a better idea how to set it different I would be glad to hear.

http://codepen.io/filaret/pen/ORNmPZ

```
ul {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 60px;
  right: -50px;
  li {
    a.btn {
      width: 50px;
      height: 46px;
      display: block;
      &:hover {
        width: 100px;
        padding-left: 50px;
      }
    }
  }
}

<div class="col col-md-8">

  ... content ...

  <ul class="share-buttons-outside list-unstyled">
    <li>
        <a class="btn" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead to position relative to right edge, do position from left:

```
ul {
    left: 100%;
    /* REMOVE right: -65px */
}
```

Comment: This works and seems the cleanest solution, I was afraid to use apsolute positioning just because of perfect pixel positioning but this clears my doubts, thank you :)

Comment: The pleasure is mine. Nema na cemu, poz

Answer (score 1):

You could add a margin to correctly position it:

```
ul li a.btn:hover {
   width: 100px;
   margin-right: -50px;
   padding-left: 50px;
}
```

This appears to correct the issue of one interacting with the other also.

Working codepen: http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/xEVdgj

Answer (score 1):

You could set a `left` value, instead of right:

```
ul {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 60px;
  left: 758;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this simple solution is enough. Instead of

```
right: -50px;
```

do

```
left: 760px;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `position: absolute;` on your `li` elements:

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yaObVg)

```
 li {
    border: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: -50px;
    top: -46px;
    &:nth-child(2) {
      top: 0;
    }
}
```